# Query DynamoDB table to fetch top 100 records order by created date

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have Dynamodb table whose primary key is partition key. This table has "created date" column also. I want to query this table to fetch top 100 records in descending order by created date. Query must have -key-condition-expression which will accept primary key of this table and it will always return maximum single record. How can I write to fetch top 100 records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read the documentation for Dynamo?

It's not an RDBMS...

In order to get more than 1 record out of DDB, you need to have a composite key (hash key + sort key)

Without knowing anything else, it sounds like you'll need to create a global secondary index with a composite key where "created date" is the sort key.

Picking the hash key for your GSI is the harder question...

Comment: After creating new index I am able to get list of sorted items through AWS console and CLI. I want write Java client using SDK 1.11.290 but not getting sample code. For example DynamoDB.getTable() is not defined where as in AWS documentation it is given